# ssh connection error when building an AWS AMI packer with minnaker provisioner script on it

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, ssh, packer

I am getting the error attached when I Build an AWS AMI with minnaker installed in it, you assit for this will be highly appreciated                                                        **'amazon-ebs' errored: Packer experienced an authentication error when trying to connect via SSH. This can happen if your username/password are wrong. You may want to double-check your credentials as part of your debugging process. original error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain**

My template.json file is as attached

{
    "variables": {
    "aws_access_key": "",
    "aws_secret_key": ""
    },

```
"builders": [
  {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "region": "us-west-2",
      "source_ami": "ami-0e32ec5bc225539f5",
      "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
      "ssh_username": "ec2-user",
      "communicator": "ssh",
      "iam_instance_profile": "{{user `iam_instance_profile`}}",
      "instance_type": "t3a.large",
      "launch_block_device_mappings": [ {
      "device_name": "/dev/sda1",
      "volume_size": 32
} 
],
      "ami_name": "minnakeramitwo - {{timestamp}}"
}
],
"provisioners": [
{
    "type": "file",
    "source": "minnaker.tgz",
    "destination": "/tmp/minnaker.tgz"
},
{

   "type": "shell",
   "inline": ["tar -xzvf /tmp/minnaker.tgz && cd minnaker && ./scripts/install.sh -o"]
}
```

]
}

Answer (score 0):

Intead ubuntu user I used root and it worked well.

```
{

"builders": [
    {
        "type": "amazon-ebs",
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "source_ami": "ami-05880939912ddc43d",
        "instance_type": "t2.micro",
        "ssh_username": "root",
        "ami_name": "xtian-mware-regner",
        "ami_description": "blue-print",
        "tags": {
            "role": "MiddleTier"
        },
        "run_tags": {
            "role": "buildSystem"
        }
    }
]
```